# How can I get google+ user profile details, given the access token and refresh token

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

Using google API

```js
function googleLogin(req, res, next) {

    var google = require('googleapis');
    var plus = google.plus('v1');
    SCOPES = 'https://mail.google.com';
    var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
    var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
        '215995260545-6rp2pg69olionsiugudcl4fni3o36ap9.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground'
    );

    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
        access_token: req.query.ac_token,
        refresh_token: req.query.rf_token
    });
    plus.people.get({
        userId: 'me',
        auth: oauth2Client
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

When I run this code, I am getting the error like `**insufficient permission**`. Am I wrong anywhere??

```
 "code": 403,
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
            "message": "Insufficient Permission"
        }
    ]
```

How can I solve this problem?? I have also referred the Gmail API scopes.

Comment: How about confirming the scopes of access token? Can you confirm the scopes included in your retrieved access token using this curl command? ``curl -d "access_token=### your access token ###" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo`` This curl command can retrieve the information of access token. By this, you can know whether your access token includes ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`` to retrieve the basic profile info. If this was not useful for solving your problem, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The main part of your problem is that you are using the wrong endpoint `https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground` is not something you can use to my knowlage

How you should be doing it

try adding the following [scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#google_sign-in)

> profile - View your basic profile info

You also shouldnt have to go though the google+ api you may be able to request the info from the userinfo endpoint but it depends on what info you are after

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=XXX

UserInfo Response

```
{
  "family_name": "Lawton", 
  "name": "Linda Lawton", 
  "picture": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAl1I/UcwPajZOuN4/photo.jpg", 
  "locale": "en", 
  "gender": "female", 
  "link": "https://plus.google.com/+LindaLawton", 
  "given_name": "Linda", 
  "id": "117200475532672775346"
}
```

People api request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

Response

```
{
  "braggingRights": "Extreme Beekeeper first to recorded an Hive inspection using Google Glass with out a veil on.", 
  "image": {
    "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAl1I/UcwPajZOuN4/photo.jpg?sz=50", 
    "isDefault": false
  }, 
  "id": "117200475532672775346", 
  "objectType": "person", 
  "verified": false, 
  "tagline": "Google Developer Expert 2014 - 2017", 
  "etag": "\"ucaTEV-ZanNH5M3SCxYRM0QRw2Y/0gZZ-LRb-PWLjbw12lr-IOAearE\"", 
  "circledByCount": 2514, 
  "occupation": "Google Developer Expert, BIA Developer at Targit", 
  .....  Lots of stuff here ...
  }
```

You should try testing using the [Oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground)

Comment: I changed it to your answer. But still no result

Comment: Did you rerun though authentication.  The user is going to have to give you permission to access profile now.

Comment: `function googleLogin(req, res, next) {

    var google = require('request');
    google('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=' + req.query.ac_token, function(err, account) {
        if (err || account.statusCode != 200) {
            return console.log('Invalid access token');
        }
    console.log("ok");
});
}`

Comment: I have totally changed to this, but it is giving an error `invalid access token`

Comment: Then request a new access token.  Access tokens are only valid for an hour you will need to request a new one.

Comment: I got same error '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}`

Comment: Insufficient Permission means that the user you are authenticated with does not have the permission to make the request you are making.   This is an issue with your authentication.